# User defined literal operator not found

Tags: c++

I am writing a class for time. Defined my own literals, but gives the error "user-defined literal operator not found".How can I correctly set a variable with a literal? Here is the literal code:
literals.hpp

```
namespace lab1 {

  ulli operator"" _d(ulli days);
  ulli operator"" _h(ulli hours);
  ulli operator"" _m (ulli minutes);
  ulli operator"" _s (ulli seconds);

}
```

literals.cpp

```
#include "literals.hpp"

  ulli operator"" _d(ulli days) {
      ulli timeInSeconds;
      timeInSeconds = days * 24 * 60 * 60;

      return timeInSeconds;
  }
....
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Timespan.hpp"
#include "Time.hpp"
#include "literals.hpp"

using namespace lab1;

int main() {

    ulli days = 12_d;
    Time Test = Time(days,24,52,32);

    std::cout << Test << std::endl;
}
```

ulli is using ulli = unsigned long long int;

Comment: what is `ulli` ? Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: ulli is using ulli = unsigned long long int;

Comment: Error still undefined reference to «lab1::operator"" _d(unsigned long long)»

Comment: The definitions are not in the same namespace as the declarations.

Comment: According to the posted code, you delcare those operators in the `lab1` namespace, but then define them in the global namespace.

Comment: the code posted would cause a different error: https://godbolt.org/z/98488x9qr. because there are 2 literal operators found (not none)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you have **declared the operator in lab1 scope but defined it in global scope.** When you move the definition also to the lab1 namespace it works.

Here is the correct code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using ulli = unsigned long long;

namespace lab1 {

  ulli operator"" _d(ulli days);
  ulli operator"" _h(ulli hours);
  ulli operator"" _m (ulli minutes);
  ulli operator"" _s (ulli seconds);

  ulli operator"" _d(ulli days) {
      ulli timeInSeconds;
      timeInSeconds = days * 24 * 60 * 60;

      return timeInSeconds;
  }

}




using namespace lab1;

int main() {

    ulli days = 12_d;
    std::cout<<days;

   return 0;
}
```